# SQL Graph: how to combine MATCH and JOIN?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Don't know how to combine MATCH and JOIN in SQL Graph Query. Error says: Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, multi part identifier "P1.IdBL" could not be bound (the one in the join clause).

```
SELECT
       P1.IDBL,
       P1.NodeName,
       COUNT(P2.NodeName) WITHIN GROUP (GRAPH PATH) AS [Depth],
       STRING_AGG(P2.NodeName,'/') WITHIN GROUP (GRAPH PATH) AS [Assembly],
       LAST_VALUE(P2.IdBL) WITHIN GROUP (GRAPH PATH) AS [Final ID BL],
       LAST_VALUE(P2.LgnBL) WITHIN GROUP (GRAPH PATH) AS [Final Lgn BL],
       LAST_VALUE(P2.IdOF) WITHIN GROUP (GRAPH PATH) AS [Final ID OF],
       LAST_VALUE(P2.IdBE) WITHIN GROUP (GRAPH PATH) AS [Final ID BE],
       LAST_VALUE(P2.LgnBE) WITHIN GROUP (GRAPH PATH) AS [Final Lgn BE]
FROM 
    ALL_NODES P1,
    ALL_NODES FOR PATH P2,
    ALL_EDGES FOR PATH E
    JOIN BL_LIVRAISON AS L ON L.BL_IdBL=P1.IdBL
WHERE MATCH(SHORTEST_PATH(P1(-(E)->P2)+))
  AND BL_Date>=@DateMin AND 
        10*1000*YEAR(BL_Date) + 100*MONTH(BL_Date) + DAY(BL_Date) <= 10*1000*YEAR(@DateMax) + 100*MONTH(@DateMax) + DAY(@DateMax);
```

Comment: Start with using all explicit joins. from all_nodes p1 join all_nodes p2 on <something> join all_edges e on <something> join bl_livraison as l on l.bl_idbl=p1.idbl

Comment: @avery_larry: you have to use cross joins for graph algorithms to work and the agreed upon style is to use commas instead of explicit `CROSS JOIN` keyword. (`agreed upon` = I haven't yet seen anyone using it)

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the MATCH query inside a common table expression, and the join on the cte.

Comment: or create a subselect from `(ALL_NODES JOIN BL_LIVRAISON WHERE ..your condition...) AS P1` subselects work better for graph algorithms. CTEs sometimes throw errors on me for no apparent reason (when the same code written as subselect works)